# Error: Optimization error [scripts.[contenthash:20].js]: X [ERROR] The symbol "merge" has already been declared

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build

I have an `angular 16` project
It gives this **error** while **building**

```
    scripts.[contenthash:20].js:22308:35:
      22308 │ import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, merge } from 'rxjs';
            ╵                                    ~~~~~

  The symbol "merge" was originally declared here:

    scripts.[contenthash:20].js:10847:1118:
      10847 │ ...End, a3 as overrides, a4 as merge, a5 as _capitalize, a6 as ...
            ╵                                ~~~~~
```

I really don't know what this error is and I don't have such code and model in the project

My construction method is as simple as this

```
ng build --configuration production --aot
```

Is